# Data governance with scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-governance

I have an ETL to analyze large data and all my tables are DataFrames with Spark 2.2.X. Now, I have to add data governance in order to know what is the origin of the data. For example:

Table A

```
| Col1 | Col2 |  
| ---- | ---- |  
| test | hello |  
| test3 | bye |
```

Table B

```
| Col1 | Col2 |  
| ---- | ---- |  
| test2 | hey |  
| test3 | bye |
```

Now I have my two tables, what I do is a join by `Col1` and `Col2 + Col2`. Resulting table:

Final Table

```
| Col1 | Col2 |  
| ---- | ---- |  
|test3 | byebye|
```

My question is, Is there any function in Spark DataFrame, API or something that does not make me change the code so much and I can show all transformations in the DataFrame that I have?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick solution for this, you can have a look at `RDD#toDebugString`. You can call the `rdd` method on your `DataFrame` and than show its lineage through this method.

Here is an example from [Jacek Laskowski's book "Mastering Apache Spark"](https://legacy.gitbook.com/book/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark/details):

```
scala> val wordCount = sc.textFile("README.md").flatMap(_.split("\\s+")).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCount: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[21] at reduceByKey at <console>:24

scala> wordCount.toDebugString
res13: String =
(2) ShuffledRDD[21] at reduceByKey at <console>:24 []
 +-(2) MapPartitionsRDD[20] at map at <console>:24 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[19] at flatMap at <console>:24 []
    |  README.md MapPartitionsRDD[18] at textFile at <console>:24 []
    |  README.md HadoopRDD[17] at textFile at <console>:24 []
```

This snippet, along with a detailed explanation about RDD lineage and `toDebugString` is available [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-lineage.html#__a_id_todebugstring_a_getting_rdd_lineage_graph_code_todebugstring_code_method).